# Issue with Cloudflare, can not access page

Tags: cloudflare

everybody.

I got an "404 not found" when trying to access the link 
   http://www.abc.com/api.php/

But the same link without backward slash is OK: 
   http://www.abc.com/module/mfox/api.php

My server using Cloudflare. And I have disabled this service, but it still happen. I also try with htaccess, but it do not work. Could anyone tell me what's the wrong here, and how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I get a 404 with both links.

Answer (score 0):

That would be on your server directly (we don't host your content). The fact that it happens with us off definitely means an issue on your server.